# Getting horizontal scrollbar because of padding

Tags: html, css

I have a full 100% div which contains a single h2 tag. Now if I put a padding then I get a scrollbar while resizing the window. This is happening because of the padding. The div is 100% width with 1002px max-width.

How can I add a left padding to the h2 tag without reducing the width max-width.

Html code

```
<div id="content-home" class="clearfix">
  <h2>Biographies</h2>
</div>
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/gu8xmt1g/1/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's because of the padding in #content-home h2.

Comment: Solved...using box-sizing. :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

#content-home h2 {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 12px 0 10px 10px;
}

#content-home{
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 1002px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content-home" class="clearfix">
  <h2>Biographies</h2>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the display:flex thing.

Answer (score 0):

you could just lower your width to fix this

```
#content-home h2 {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  max-width: 1002px;
  padding: 12px 0 10px 10px;
  width: 99%;
}
```